# Is it possible (how to) name tensorflow node, obtained by formula?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Suppose I have

```
R_cap_i_ff = tf.get_variable('R_cap_i_ff', [batch_size, n_components])
R_cap_j_ff = tf.get_variable('R_cap_j_ff', [batch_size, n_components])
```

These are 2 variables, which has the same name in Python and in TF graph.

Then I have

```
x = tf.einsum('ij,ij->i', R_cap_i_ff, tf.transpose(R_cap_j_ff))
```

Can I give tensorflow name to `x` and how to do this?

Comment: `x = tf.identity(x, name='some_name')`

Comment: doesn't this create separate node with name?

Comment: yes it creates a copy.